# Select XML nodes based on matching values in other nodes

Tags: xpath, xslt-1.0

Given the following xml

```
<dsQueryResponse>
<Proposals>
    <Rows>
        <Row ID="1"/>
        <Row ID="2"/>
        <Row ID="3"/>
    </Rows>
</Proposals>
<ProposalReviewers>
    <Rows>
        <Row ID="1" ProposalID="1"/>
        <Row ID="2" ProposalID="1"/>
        <Row ID="3" ProposalID="2"/>
    </Rows>
   </ProposalReviewers>
</dsQueryResponse>
```

What xpath expression, or XSLT transform (Xslt 1.0), will give me the following output, based on the values of attribute ProposalID?

```
<Rows>
    <Row ID="1"/>
    <Row ID="2"/>
</Rows>
```

I know if I'm running inside of a for-each I can use current(), but I am hoping to do this outside the for-each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question can be read in many ways, and I am mostly guessing here. Still, the only logical way to return only the two Rows from the input that has three (or six), seems to be this:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="proposal" match="Proposals/Rows/Row" use="@ID" />

<xsl:template match="/dsQueryResponse">
    <Rows>
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('proposal', ProposalReviewers/Rows/Row/@ProposalID)"/>
    </Rows>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To understand how this works, see: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key